# Type is not defined error - Design view - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, class, namespaces, custom-controls

Apologies in advance. I've always struggled to get my head around the namespaces, classes, methods, references, libraries etc.

I've saved the code below as a class and separate file in my project. It basically allows you to include Slider Controls on ContextMenus. I can include this new control on existing forms via Designer no problem.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.Design

<ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.ContextMenuStrip), DebuggerStepThrough()>
Public Class TrackBarMenuItem
    Inherits ToolStripControlHost

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(New TrackBar())
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property TrackbarControl() As TrackBar
        Get
            Return CType(Control, TrackBar)
        End Get
    End Property

    ' PROPERTIES
    ' Add properties, events etc. you want to expose...

    Public Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return TrackbarControl.Value
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            TrackbarControl.Value = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Minimum() As Integer
        Get
            Return TrackbarControl.Minimum
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            TrackbarControl.Minimum = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Maximum() As Integer
        Get
            Return TrackbarControl.Maximum
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            TrackbarControl.Maximum = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LargeChange() As Integer
        Get
            Return TrackbarControl.LargeChange
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            TrackbarControl.LargeChange = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property SmallChange() As Integer
        Get
            Return TrackbarControl.SmallChange
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            TrackbarControl.SmallChange = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Orientation() As Integer
        Get
            Return TrackbarControl.Orientation
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            TrackbarControl.Orientation = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TickFrequency() As Integer
        Get
            Return TrackbarControl.TickFrequency
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            TrackbarControl.TickFrequency = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TickStyle() As Integer
        Get
            Return TrackbarControl.TickStyle
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            TrackbarControl.TickStyle = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'EVENTS:
    Protected Overrides Sub OnSubscribeControlEvents(ByVal c As Control)
        ' Call the base so the base events are connected. 
        MyBase.OnSubscribeControlEvents(c)
        ' Cast the control to a Taskbar control. 
        Dim trackbarcontrol As TrackBar = CType(c, TrackBar)
        ' Add the events: 
        AddHandler trackbarcontrol.ValueChanged, AddressOf HandleValueChanged
        'AddHandler trackbarcontrol.Scroll, AddressOf HandleScroll
    End Sub

    ' Slider changed event
    Public Event SliderValueChanged As EventHandler
    Private Sub HandleValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent SliderValueChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(ByVal c As Control)
        ' Call the base method so the basic events are unsubscribed. 
        MyBase.OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(c)
        ' Cast the control to a MonthCalendar control. 
        Dim monthCalendarControl As MonthCalendar = _
            CType(c, MonthCalendar)
        ' Remove the event. 
        RemoveHandler TrackbarControl.ValueChanged, AddressOf HandleValueChanged
    End Sub

End Class
```

However, there are errors prior to compile of the full code like this:

```
Error   5   Type 'CPWBAdmin.TrackBarMenuItem' is not defined.   C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CPWBAdmin\CPWBAdmin\MarqueeEditor.Designer.vb  208 34  CPWBAdmin
```

In designer view, an example offending article:

```
  Me._ImgBrightnessSlider = New CPWBAdmin.TrackBarMenuItem()
```

If I change this to:

```
  Me._ImgBrightnessSlider = New Global.CPWBAdmin.TrackBarMenuItem()
```

Then it compiles and runs fine. *Until* the next time I edit the control, and the error re-appears again.

Reading around, possibly something to do with Class name 'matching the namespace' - but I have no idea how to determine what the namespace is for this class (filename?).

Sure this is a basic for a lot of the pros out there so any help of an amateur would be appreciated!

Comment: It partly depends on how the Solution is configured.  You might be able to wrap your control inside a `Namespace StigzlerControls` then import `StigzlerControls` in the project using the control/menu thing

Comment: Have other custom classes (basic, such as 'videobox' inherits just 'picturebox') which do not cause this problem - no need to import anything - can just reference these new classes (separate save files) within any script in the project. Also, how do I do anything of what you suggested? Sorry - don;'t understand the terminology. Thanks for the response.

Comment: BTW, you can find out the namespace "root" from Project-> Properties -> .Application.Root NameSpace which defaults to the app name such as `WindowsApplication17`.  VB will append any others you specify, so your control could become `WindowsApplication17.StigzlerControls.TrackBarMenuItem` See [Namespaces in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: Sorry - still don't get it. Tried enclosing Class above in `Namespace CustomMenuControls` and then, on a form wishing to use it on put `Include CPWBAdmin.CustomMenuControls.TrackBarMenuItem.` Same errors remain and now set of new ones of type: `Error 12 'Image' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost, System.Drawing'. C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CPWBAdmin\CPWBAdmin\MarqueeEditor.vb 631 35 CPWBAdmin'`

Comment: @stigzler - VB does not have an `Include` statement but it does have an `Imports` statement.  Also you cannot `Import` a class, only a namespace so perhaps it should be `Imports CPWBAdmin.CustomMenuControls`?

Comment: Apologies - typo. I meant `Imports`  - that's what I tried. With the namespace only.